# How to generate HTML report with screenshots

Tags: pytest, pytest-html

import pytest

import uiautomator2 as u2

d=u2.connect()

def test_precondition():

```
d.press(“home”)
```

def test_procedure():

```
d(text=“Settings”).click()

d.screenshot(“Settings.png”)

d(text=“Bluetooth”).click()

d.screenshot(“Bluetooth.png”)
```

def test_expectedResult():

```
assert d(text=“Bluetooth”).exists
```

running above script as : py.test --html=report.html --self-contained-html Bluetooth settings.py

I am new to python When I am running the above script with pytest and generating HTML report I am unable to see screenshot image in HTML report requesting to please provide solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default pytest-html captures and attaches screenshot for only failed test cases, If you want it to capture for passed test cases too. You can refer the following thread [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099835/how-to-include-selenium-screenshot-in-pytest-bdd-for-passed-tests/48163452#48163452)